# Bug in Krusader lost directory subtree. How to recover the files?

Tags: filesystem, fsck, data-loss, krusader

Using Krusader version 2.4.0-beta1 (thanks Canonical for using me as ginnea pig without my knowledge), I renamed two directories to replace the spaces in the names with underscores. Unfortunately, immediately after doing so, the files and directories below my `Security Web` directory completely vanished.

How can I recover them?

The path I altered was:
    /home/peter/Documents/Business from 2005/Security Web/

Which should have become:
    /home/peter/Documents/Business_from_2005/Security_Web/

I've altered it back, in the hope that the files would reappear, but they didn't.

I have just one disk, this being a laptop and it's all one partition, except for swap.

I attempted to force a disk check at the next restart using:
    touch ./forcefsck

But it didn't seem to work since the next startup took no longer than normal despite having nearly 400GB of files to check.

Also the above fsck method seems somewhat lame to me (even if it did work), since how can you pass parameters to fsck? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below link may be useful to you...
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: Thanks. I have a back up which is about 8 hours old. Which means I'll only have lost the last 8 hours work if I restore from that. I think the method you suggested would be ideal if it was more than a days work lost, but will probably take longer than redoing my work. Thanks anyway.